# Hibernate: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, maven

In my application just one simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id int, 
    first_name varchar(40) not null, 
    last_name varchar(40) not null, 
    gender varchar(40) not null, 
    married bool not null, 
    profile varchar(40) not null);
```

Also I use thymeleaf for get and set data from web interface. This structure of project:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgION.png)

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion><groupId>com.nfhktwrbq</groupId>
<artifactId>sbth</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>sbth</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>



<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <hibernate-version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate-version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">muaddib</property>
    <property name="connection.password">catch22</property>
    <mapping class="com.nfhktwrbq.sbth.UsersEntity"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

UsersController.java

```java
package com.nfhktwrbq.sbth.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import com.nfhktwrbq.sbth.HibernateSessionFactory;
import com.nfhktwrbq.sbth.UsersEntity;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.nfhktwrbq.sbth.service.UserService;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("app")
public class UserController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @GetMapping("create-user")
    public ModelAndView createUserView() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("user-creation");
        mav.addObject("user", new UsersEntity());
        mav.addObject("allProfiles", getProfiles());
        return mav;
    }
    @PostMapping("create-user")
    public ModelAndView createUser(@Valid UsersEntity user, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            logger.info("Validation errors while submitting form.");
            mav.setViewName("user-creation");
            mav.addObject("user", user);
            mav.addObject("allProfiles", getProfiles());
            return mav;
        }
        userService.addUser(user);
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();       
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        mav.addObject("allUsers", userService.getAllUserArticles());
        mav.setViewName("user-info");
        logger.info("Form submitted successfully.");
        return mav;
    }
    @GetMapping("show-users")
    public ModelAndView showUsersView() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("user-all");
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<UsersEntity> ueList = session.createQuery("from UsersEntity").list();
        for (UsersEntity ent : ueList) {
            logger.info(ent.getFirstName());
        }
        mav.addObject("users", ueList);
        session.close();
        return mav;
    }
    private List<String> getProfiles() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Developer");
        list.add("Manager");
        list.add("Director");
        return list;
    }
}
```

UsersEntity.java

```java
package com.nfhktwrbq.sbth;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users_tb", schema = "public", catalog = "muaddib")
public class UsersEntity {
    private Integer userId;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=40)
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=40)
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull
    private String gender;
    private boolean married;
    private String profile;


    @Id   
    @Column(name = "user_id")    
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 40)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 40)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false, length = 40)
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "married", nullable = false)
    public boolean isMarried() {
        return married;
    }

    public void setMarried(boolean married) {
        this.married = married;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "profile", nullable = false, length = 40)
    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(String profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UsersEntity that = (UsersEntity) o;

        if (userId != that.userId) return false;
        if (married != that.married) return false;
        if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(that.firstName) : that.firstName != null) return false;
        if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(that.lastName) : that.lastName != null) return false;
        if (gender != null ? !gender.equals(that.gender) : that.gender != null) return false;
        if (profile != null ? !profile.equals(that.profile) : that.profile != null) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        int result = userId == null ? 0: userId.intValue();
        result = 31 * result + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (gender != null ? gender.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (married ? 1 : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (profile != null ? profile.hashCode() : 0);        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Error appears in line `session.save(user)`
I'm trying do different things,add default constructor etc, but always get error:

> IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of
>   com.nfhktwrbq.sbth.UsersEntity.userId

This is simple app with one table. What hibernate wants?

```
2017-10-03 13:33:04.964  INFO 3863 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@70d925c5
2017-10-03 13:33:05.781 ERROR 3863 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.p.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl        : HHH000122: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.nfhktwrbq.sbth.UsersEntity, getter method of property: userId
2017-10-03 13:33:05.839 ERROR 3863 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.nfhktwrbq.sbth.UsersEntity.userId] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4646) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:673) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:660) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at com.nfhktwrbq.sbth.controller.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Comment: Wheres the CausedBy line?

Comment: Fullstacktrace needed - this line says nothing

Comment: Object is not an instance of declaring class in trace. But this is internal things of hibernate, connected with reflections mechanism, I think.